Keeping my passport while waiting for my UK visa application
I plan to go on two trips from Iran to China and the UK in the coming month, first to China for around three weeks, and then I will come back and a week later go to the UK.
Unfortunately, I could not get an appointment for a UK visa in time. The company that handles visa appointments in my country (VFS Global) offers a service where you can hold your passport until the embassy decides on your visa application.
I plan to use this service, and I want to know how much time I have to return my passport after they reach the decision. Can I postpone it until I come back from my trip to China? Is one week is enough for getting the visa?

What did VFS say when you asked them?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
